# How to substitute `$variable` within bash cat `<< 'EOF' >`?

Tags: bash

I write bash `cat << 'EOF' >` script to create files.script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for sitename in (site1,site2,site3)
    do
    cat << 'EOF' >/home/$sitename/conf
DEPLOY_DIR="/var/www/$sitename"
git --work-tree="DEPLOY_DIR"
EOF
    done
```

The result after run this script should like:

```
[root@localhost]cat home/site1/conf
DEPLOY_DIR="/var/www/site1"
git --work-tree="$DEPLOY_DIR"
```

The **key** is I need to substitute `$sitename` in `DEPLOY_DIR="/var/www/$sitename"` and keep `git --work-tree="DEPLOY_DIR"` as same.
How to do it?

Comment: @Inian,if I use `<< EOF`,`"$DEPLOY_DIR"` will become `""`

Comment: I added a new answer to the duplicate explaining how to avoid expansion of some strings. Also the `for` loop looks wrong here -- you want `for sitename in site1 site2 site3; do`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
for sitename in site1 site2 site3;do
    cat << EOF > /home/$sitename/conf
    DEPLOY_DIR="/var/www/$sitename"
    git --work-tree="\$DEPLOY_DIR"
EOF
done
```

Comment: That's  workable, but if you have lots of  `$variables` , hard work.

Comment: This is the only way you will be able to extrapolate some variables while not extrapolating others.  The other way would require more typing.